# Основные направления в JAVA

Tags: java

Вопрос к программистам пишущим на JAVA.
Недавно стал изучать JAVA (до этого писал на Delphi), планирую через два-три года найти работу программистом.
Нужен совет: 
 - какие в основном задачи ставят перед программистом на JAVA?
 - какие направления возможно будут востребованы больше через пару лет?
 - просто рекомендации тех, кто уже давно в этой сфере.

Comment: 'JAVA' - точно не будет востребована. А в Java можно делать чтото для веба (бек-энд), или для Андроида

Comment: Если хотите чего-то серьезного (через несколько лет), то можете посмотреть в сторону [Hadoop](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop).

Comment: @argamidon ну все, написал капсом - запинаем парня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если решили стать программистом Java, то смело им становитесь. Рекомендую почитать книгу: "Java. Библиотека профессионала. Том 1. Основы" Авторы: Кей С. Хорстманн, Гари Корнелл. В этой книге подробно описано про язык. В самом начале книги описано чем Java является и чем не является. Прочтете первый том, приступайте ко второму, а там затянет и пойдет поедет! :)

Comment: >Самое немаловажное это не просто найти вакансию интересную, а еще на эту вакансию пройти собеседование

зачем так капитанствовать? Еще скажите, что на работе нужно работать

Comment: >  С капитанством можно столкнуться, когда будете работать в большом проекте совместно с профессионалами

пардон, вы  о чем вообще?

Comment: Да, именно с этих книжек я и начал. 
Насколько я понял JAVA через пару лет будет актуальна, значит можно продолжать.
Благодарю!

Comment: >JAVA через пару лет будет актуальна

уверяю вас, Java и через 20 лет будет актуальна. И, возможно, даже через 50

Comment: А на какие направления все же стоит обратить внимание (в плане перспективных): Андроид, web приложения или что-то еще. Извиняюсь, если это глупые вопросы, просто хочется быть уверенным что время потрачу не зря.

Comment: @kaaa изучите сам язык(благо он несложен), ООП, алгоритмы, основы проектирования - в общем, все то, что нужно во все времена. А потом уже обращайте внимание на конкретные особенности конкретных платформ - с готовым базисом это учится существенно быстрей. Однако можно на 146% быть уверенным, что и через два года популярные нынче технологии останутся такими же популярными

Comment: @DreamChild, скажите, пожалуйста, а какой язык стоит ещё подучить на всякий случай? Вдруг Java популярность таки потеряет) Что будет котироваться ещё долго - C++/C# или Haskell?

Comment: @SuperCreeper блин, вы прикалываетесь что ли?

Comment: >саму структуру объектной ориентированности. Что куда и откуда берется. В XML необходимо вникнуть

>Android конечно тема, но Microsoft уже смазывает глаз на Android и хотят забрать его у Google

@Vladimir991 извините конечно, но что вы бред-то несете?

Comment: >Я может неправильно понял

@Vladimir991 если вы прочтете эту вашу статью дальше заголовка, то увидите, что именно заголовок у нее имеет весьма слабое отношение как к содержимому статьи, так и к реальности вообще. К томе же еще не факт, что сама целиком статья правдива

Comment: Благодарю всех за ответы. Буду учить дальше, пока есть возможность. А года через два можно будет себя попробовать в деле.